# Most convenient way to deallocate multiple memory pointers?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm looking for most convenient/best/smartest way for multiple memory deallocation. Not quite sure if that is best explanation out there, but here is an example that will show what i want to do:

```
void func()
{
    int* ptr1 = malloc(1);
    if(ptr1 == NULL)
    {
        //...
    }

    int* ptr2 = malloc(1);
    if(ptr2 == NULL)
    {
        //...
        free(ptr1);
    }

    int* ptr3 = malloc(1);
    if(ptr3 == NULL)
    {
        //...
        free(ptr2);
        free(ptr1);
    }

    //code...
}
```

Only thing that comes up to my mind is array filled with flags, if the flag is raised particular memory has to be freed. Is there any other more convenient way to do this? You can imagine how many times i need to repeat `free()` if there is need for more `malloc()`-ing.

Comment: Put them in an array which is NULL terminated/initialized and iterate that array.

Comment: I'm hoping there is another way to do that except using an array.

Comment: `ptr1* = malloc(1);` is complete nonsense. please post real code.

Comment: @joop How is that nonsense? Assuming that ptr1, ptr2 and ptr3 are global variables.

Comment: @SirDrinksCoffeeALot _I'm hoping there is another way to do that except using an array_ : no there isn't.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, try to compile it. C only has `*` as a prefix operator.

Comment: You could (and, perhaps, should, unless you are writing code for tiny embedded systems) use a modern C++ version with smart pointers which do all the book-keeping for you. It's almost as good as full-scale garbage collection.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, comments about utilities from other programming languages are out-of-scope of the question, I think.

Comment: With gcc you can use __attribute__ cleanup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001002/how-to-initialize-variable-with-cleanup-attribute.

Comment: @JensGustedt "Try to compile it": Oh. True. "other programming languages are out-of-scope": Hm. Expanding the answer space is sometimes a good thing. The OP may not be aware of the benefits of modern C++.

Comment: I did not pay attention on syntax, my bad. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you posted is a common practice for error handling and resource release in a function, you acquire several resources and in case any error occurred, you need to release those that have been acquired prior, there is nothing wrong, just do it one by one.

```
void func(void) {
    void *ptr1 = NULL;
    void *ptr2 = NULL;
    void *ptr3 = NULL;

    ptr1 = malloc(SIZE);
    if (!ptr1) goto end;

    ptr2 = malloc(SIZE);
    if (!ptr2) goto end;

    ptr3 = malloc(SIZE);
    if (!ptr3) goto end;

    // do your work with the buffers

end:
    free(ptr1);
    free(ptr2);
    free(ptr3);
}
```

Comment: @user694733, that would make the code depend on the behavior (implementation) of `free` to not crash on freeing a NULL pointer. I agree with the original, defensive and correct approach of testing ptr for NULL before calling free.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie C standard (from draft N1570) chapter 7.22.3.3 says: *"The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. ..."*

Comment: @user694733, standards change. Past standards didn't have this. The code is not defensive. It causes potentially unnecesary function calls. My argument maybe opinion based.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie *standards change* Exactly. Therefore there is no need to adhere to arhaic rules and check for NULL before freeing. (free is defined as such at least since (including) c89 and on)

Comment: Yeah, but what if your malloc fails on ptr2, then you go to end and try to free ptr2 and ptr3 which are not yet allocated and you'll get error trying to free non-allocated memory?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `array of pointers` and keep count of the  number of `malloc`s done. And use a common free function to `free` them all. Like,

```
void func()
{
    char* ptr[10];
    int n = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ptr[i] = NULL;

    ptr[n] = malloc(1);
    if(ptr[n] == NULL)
    {
        //...
    }
    n++;

    ptr[n] = malloc(1);
    if(ptr[n] == NULL)
    {
        //...
        custom_free(ptr1, n);
    }
    n++;

    ptr[n] = malloc(1);
    if(ptr[n] == NULL)
    {
        //...
        custom_free(ptr, n);
    }
    n++;
    //code...
}
```

And the `custom_free()` can be something like,

```
void custom_free(char* ptr[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to allocate all needed memory in one big chunk,
and treat *parts* of that as p0,p1,p2:

```
void worker(void)
{
#define N_ELEM 123
int *work_mem;
int *p0,*p1,*p2;

work_mem = malloc ( 3* N_ELEM * sizeof *work_mem);
if (!work_mem) { OMG(); return; }

p0 = work_mem, p1= work_mem + N_ELEM, p2 = work_mem + 2 * N_ELEM;

        /* do useful stuff here with work_mem
        ** , possibly via p0,p1,p2
         */

free(work_mem);
}
```

Comment: While this can work, you have to make sure manually that all pointers are correctly aligned. It would be more safe to place all variables in single structure, and let compiler sort out alignment details.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to take care of correctness in the original case, too. [the `int *p = malloc(1);` in the (corrected) question will be not suited for even storing a single int, for instance]

Comment: True, but that is issue with size, not alignment. But even size issue is easier to handle with struct, assuming required size is static as in your example: `CombinedType * data = malloc(sizeof *data);`

Comment: Basically, size and alignment are two manifestations of the same thing. (and in practice, `sizeof` is your friend) I am not giving a *general solution to everything* here, just a code pattern that in some cases can be useful.

Comment: It's not general solution, and that's why there should be warning about possible alignment issues. When using mixed types, beginner might not be aware why `malloc(3)` is not enough for his `uint8_t *p0, uint16_t *p1;` on usual systems.